# Double tables with code migrations

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, code-migration, entity-framework-6

I have a big database which concists of 2 parts: a backoffice and frontend part. The backoffice part never changes per project so they have their own assembly for business and data.

The data layer has it's own code-migrations and it's own `DbContext` called `BackofficeContext`. The schema is `Backoffice`

The frontend has the same structure, also it's own data layer, it's own code-migrations and a `DbContext` called `FrontendContext`. This has a different schema `Frontend`.

In the database I will see a clear seperation of Backoffice and Frontend related tables, which is what I want.

There is only one problem. One table in the `FrontendContext` contains a field to the `BackofficeContext`:

```
public class UserChoise
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid UserChoiseId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

The user table is in the `BackofficeContext`, the `UserChoises` table is in the `FrontendContext`.

When I run the code-migration for the `BackofficeContext` it will create a table for `Users`. When I run code-migrations for the `FrontendContext` it will create the `UserChoises` table, but also AGAIN the `Users` table.

I can remove this table by hand from the migrations file but it comes back everytime I make a new migration.

Is there a way to make the `FrontendContext` aware of the `BackofficeContext`?

Comment: Do you ever traverse this navigation property? If not, you could just remove it and add the foreign key constraint after-the-fact inside of the migration's Up method.

Comment: Did exactly that yes. But what a better solution is (for some): remove 1 of the contexts and make it a BaseContext, then extend the other context from that one. Basically migrations will see it as 1 big context. But your schema's won't work anymore then.